# Multiplication formula for Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Citing Stein and Weiss' "Introduction to Fourier Analysis", if $f,g\in L^1$ then we have the so-called Multiplication formula:
$$ \int \hat f g\,dx = \int f\,\hat g\, dx $$
The proof is just a couple of lines:

$$ \int \hat f(x) g(x)\,dx = \int\left( \int f(t)e^{-2\pi i\, tx}\,dt\right) g(x)\, dx = \\ \int\left( \int g(x)e^{-2\pi i\, tx}\,dx\right) f(t)\, dt = \int f(t)\,\hat g(t)\, dt$$

My question is: in order to apply Fubini's theorem, shouldn't we require also that $~fg\in L^1$? I don't see why the hypotheses of Fubini's theorem are met otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int \int |f(t)g(x)|\, dt\, dx=(\int|f(t)|\, dt )(\int |g(x)|\, dx) <\infty$ so Fubini's Theorem is applicable.